# Push bokeh BoxAnnotation to the background

Tags: python, bokeh

I have constructed a bokeh plot which I run in a `Jupyter` notebook. It displays "classic" glyphs, as well as `BoxAnnotations` that enable me to highlight periods of time depending on status (see image below).

[image: bokeh plot with foreground BoxAnnotations]

What annoys me is that the BoxAnnotations seem to always be in the foreground, and therefore prevent users from clearly seeing colors.

I tried to switch the commands to add the annotations and the glyphs, but without success.

Is there any way to push the `BoxAnnotation` to the background, or are layouts always in the foreground?
Is there any other way to achieve the plotting I would like to produce?

Comment: You can try adding `level="underlay"` when you create your BoxAnnotation: `BoxAnnotation(..., level="underlay")` not certain this will work, which is why I'm leaving it as a comment.

Comment: Thanks, @CameronRiddell, this worked like a charm. If you would post it as an answer I would gladly tag it as the accepted answer. I'll give you a couple of days before posting it myself to give visibility for other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding level="underlay" when you create your BoxAnnotation:

```
BoxAnnotation(..., level="underlay")
```

This is a feature of the Bokeh `Annotation` base class, where you can specify any of the following levels: `image, underlay, glyph, guide, annotation, overlay` I believe they are in incremental order from background -> foreground.

They have a brief snippet of it in the [`Label`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#userguide-plotting-labels) section of their user-guide. Though I do find the documentation of it to be a little lacking.